# Add user defined fields in the FIX dictionary

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I need to add/modify fields in the FIX4.4 dictionary. I haven't found any helpful documentation or tutorials on this.

I'm guessing I have to modify the FIX44.xml file, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that.
In the `<message></message>` tags I don't see any attributes that define the number or the type(format) of that field. I see just the `name` and `required` attributes.

I think I found attributes I', looking for in the `<fields></fields>` tags.

I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place or if I'm doing the right thing, but according to [this](http://b2bits.blogspot.ro/2011/02/fix-protocol-and-user-defined-fields-in.html) I should modify the dictionary if it is necessary.

Please help.
A link to a tutorial for beginners that can help me would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tutorial is for changing the dictionary for FIXML messages not for FIX messages. Am I correct that you are trying to add user defined fields for FIX messages not FIXML messages ?

Comment: I want to edit the FIX.4.4 dictionary to add new messages and new fields.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The FIX Data Dictionary in QuickFIX contains Messages and Fields (among other things).

To add Messages you must add the message between the `<messages></messages>` tags like this:

```
<message name="CoolMessage" msgcat="app" msgtype="xCM">
    <field name="Currency" required="N"/>
    <field name="Text" required="N"/>
    <field name="Account" required="Y"/>
</message>
```

And then add the new `msgtype` to the `MsgType` field in the `<fields></fields>` section like this:

```
<field number='35' name='MsgType' type='STRING'>
    ...
    <value enum='xCM' description='COOLMESSAGE'/>
</field>
```

If you want to add new fields, just add them between the `<fields></fields>` tags like this:

```
<fields>
    <field number="1" name="Account" type="STRING"/>
    <field number="2" name="AdvId" type="STRING"/>
    <field number="3" name="AdvRefID" type="STRING"/>
    ...
    <field number="9006" name="AwesomeField" type="STRING"/>
</fields>
```

This and more information can be found in [this](http://www.quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages) tutorial.